# example :concatenation of 2 undecidable language gives a decidable language

Tags: automata-theory

give example of 2 languages A and B such that A and B are undecidable but there concatenation A.B is decidable.

Comment: This looks like homework to me; I'll vote to close.


Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: yes you can delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ contain all even-length strings, plus an undecidable collection of odd-length strings. Let $B$ contain all odd-length strings, plus the empty string, plus an undecidable collection of even-length strings. So each is undecidable, but the concatenation $AB$ consists of all strings and hence is decidable.

Comment: in place of undecidable set of odd/even length string if i just take union of odd length string+halting problem+null (same for even), it will work i feel

Comment: I tried to delete, but unfortunately, the software does not seem to allow me to delete an accepted answer. (And since it is now off the main page anyway, and closed anyway, perhaps it is best simply to let it rest...)